# ReactJS: How to switch video tags just when one is ready to play to not show the loading black screen?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, video, next.js, video.js

### Background

I have a video player, an instance of [VideoJS](https://videojs.com/guides/react/). The player receives `videoData` via a socket event `video_data` from the server. Then it changes the video source to the one that is received.

The server is running on-premise, all video files, database is hosted on-premise. So there is close to 0 network latency.

### The problem

A black screen appears while the browser loads the video data. I would like to tune it further and not show the black screen at all.

### My solution

Here is my approach: I want to create two video instances (`<video>` tags) and switch between them. The first one is hidden and the second one is visible. When it receives video data, rather than changing the source of the current visible `<video>`  tag, it changes the source of the hidden `<video>` tag. Just when hidden `<video>` tag is ready to play ([`onCanPlay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) event), it switches the visibility of the two `<video>` tags. Ideally that's how the black screen will not be visible at all.

### Sample source code

```js
// ---------- Index.tsx ----------
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import videojs, { VideoJsPlayerOptions } from "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";
import { VideoDataWithOptions } from "../../@types/types";
import { socket } from "../../lib/socket";
import VideoPlayer from "./VideoPlayer";

const hlsVideoJsOptions: VideoJsPlayerOptions = {
  autoplay: true,
  muted: false,
  controls: true,
  loop: false,
  sources: [
    {
      src: "",
      type: "application/x-mpegURL",
    },
  ],
};

const Index = () => {
  const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState({} as VideoDataWithOptions);

  useEffect((): any => {
    socket.on("videoData", data => {
      const options = {
        ...hlsVideoJsOptions,
        sources: [
          {
            src: `/videos/destination/${data.path}`,
            type: "application/x-mpegURL",
          },
        ],
      };
      setVideoData({ ...data, options });
    });

    return () => socket.off("videoData");
  }, []);

  return <VideoPlayer videoData={videoData}></VideoPlayer>;
};

export default Index;






// ---------- VideoPlayer.tsx ----------
type Props = { videoData: VideoDataWithOptions }; // ex. => { path: string, title: string, loop: boolean, options: VideoJsPlayerOptions, ... }

const VideoPlayer = ({ videoData }: Props) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const playerRef = useRef<any>(null); // null

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      const videoElement = videoRef.current;

      if (!videoElement) return;

      playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, videoData.options, () => {});
    } else {
    }
  }, [videoData, videoRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={videoRef} className="video-js" playsInline />
      {/* <video ref={videoRef} className="video-js" playsInline /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;


// How should I go about this?
```

### Dev environment

- [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/)
- [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, your `videoData` is gonna change repeatedly, so you need to switch between the two `<video />` elements and there's always only one of them visible.

Now think about it, `videoData` is the only variable, and there's very little view reactivity attach to it. My solution is based on this fact, it's very "un-react", very opinionated. In fact I'mma only use react to load and unload two `<video />` elements, and the rest is all taken cared by imperative code.

```
type RefHolder = {
  current: HTMLVideoElement | null;
  player: any | null;
};

type VideoPlayerInternalState = { 
  flag: number;
  video_1: RefHolder;
  video_2: RefHolder;  
};

const VideoPlayer = ({ videoData }: Props) => {
  const state = useRef<VideoPlayerInternalState>({
    flag: 0,
    video_1: { current: null, player: null },
    video_2: { current: null, player: null },
  }).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    // use a odd/even flag to switch between 2 `<video />` element
    let ref: RefHolder, other_ref: RefHolder;
    if (state.flag % 2 == 0) {
      ref = state.video_1;
      other_ref = state.video_2;
    } else {
      ref = state.video_2;
      other_ref = state.video_1;
    }

    // if, for whatever reason, element not found,
    // which normally shouldn't happen, we just abort.
    if (!ref.current) return;

    // bump the flag, so that next time `videoData` change,
    // we'll switch to the other `<video />` element
    state.flag += 1;
    
    if (!ref.player) {
      ref.player = videojs(ref.current, videoData.options, () => {});
    }

    // attach once event listener
    const onCanPlay = () => {
      ref.current.classList.add("visible");
      other_ref.current.classList.remove("visible");
      // autoplay? you decide
      ref.player.play();
    };
    ref.player.one("canplay", onCanPlay);
    ref.player.src(videoData.options.sources);

    // I'm not sure about your scenario
    // but you might wanna cancel the pending effect
    // in case `videoData` switches too fast
    const cancelPending = () => {
      ref.player.off("canplay", onCanPlay);
    }

    return cancelPending;

  }, [videoData]); // <-- We only react to videoData change

  useEffect(() => {
    const onUnmounted = () => {
      state.video_1.player?.dispose();
      state.video_2.player?.dispose();
    };
    return onUnmounted;
  }, [])

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={state.video_1} className="video-js visible" playsInline />
      <video ref={state.video_2} className="video-js" playsInline />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Comment: I got it working, thanks to you. Can I follow up with a few questions?

Comment: sure, go ahead.